# Migrating consideration Asp.Net webforms/ MVC website from dedicated to cloud hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cloud-hosting, dedicated-server

I have a requirement where i have an option of migrating all website which are asp.net webform & MVC based to a new dedicated server or Cloud server. I am not much aware of internal dynamic of clod hosting and most of the providers are not clear about the concerns i have.

Let me put it this way.

- I use asp.net session variable in bot webforms & MVC how can i handle these session on cloud hosting Will session variable break in cloud enviroment in case single user session is severed by multiple instance on different servers in cloud
- I am Using MS SQL Server 2008 R2 edition what should i consider for cloud
- We have Apple Push certificate installed on dedicated server can we install same on cloud server
- Can we have FULL TRUST level in cloud as we are using one application which need FULL TRUST level access to work.
- Is there different version of Plesk for cloud server or we can install same Plesk etc.

If issue is with defaul session In-Proc then i can use SQL Server based session to get around it.

Do i need to take into consideration anything that can effect websites from working on cloud from configuration point of view or code point of view.

What steps should i take for migration from windows dedicated server to cloud server.

Comment: The best answer that I can think of for this question is that you have to log in to the cloud provider and try to create the environment that you want and see what stumbling blocks you face - and then fix them.  Amazon AWS has a free tier that will allow you to experiment with their services for free.  Create a small MSSQL server and spin up an EC2 instance.  Without doing this you're not going to learn.  I know it's a bit harsh to say, but it's true.  I was in the same position as you a year and a half ago and just giving things a go is the only way to become familiar with it.

Comment: On hardware level, there is no difference between cloud servers and you on-premise/dedicated servers. You can use the same software's/tools that you were using earlier. Regarding SQL server, you can just choose the version of your choice.